# Which kind of Flash supports "Bit-alterable write operations" right now?

Tags: programming, flash, ram

I'm very desperate not to find any suitable alternative for a discontinued PRAM (Phase-change memory) Flash. My colleague has developed a device which uses this PRAM  Flash and especially its "**Bit-alterable write operation**".

So my problem is to find any other Flash type which supports this operation. The whole PRAM Flash technology were discontinued in 2013... The specific IC to replace can be found here:

http://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/micron-technology-inc/NP5Q128AE3ESFC0E/NP5Q128AE3ESFC0E-ND/4316956

**Main Features for an alternative:**

- Bit alterable write function
- 128 Mbit space
- About 100.000 write cycles
- About 30 MHz clock frequency
- SPI Interface

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"Customers should discuss potential migration options with their Micron sales representative."_, apparently "MAURIZIO BELTRAMELLO" in your case.

Comment: They don't answer to my request...

Comment: Well, as the product change notice says, "there is no direct migration path". So any replacement will be dependent on your requirements. Aside from bit-by-bit write, what properties of this device were you depending on in your product? How fast does it need to be, and how often are you reading/writing it?

Comment: You might be able to find an MRAM or FeRAM device that works as you want. If anyone has made one with that sort of functionality...

Comment: Sometimes you can change your 'file system' to mark a page as bad if it is not possible to unwrite a desired bit and then just write a new block with the current data.  This is only suitable if you have space capacity and processing time.

Comment: I just added the wished features

Comment: As it stands, this is off topic, because you are trying to purchase to fill an opaque requirement, and shopping questions are off topic.  If you re-write it to be clear about *exactly* how the bit-alterable capability is *utilized* and *why* then there could potentially be an on-topic engineering question about how to find the minimum change of strategy that will allow you to use a different memory type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rethink** the application to determine how you can use a smaller amount of the memory in the application. Quite possibly the part being replaced was 128 Mbit simply because the technology steered toward parts of that density and not that the product application actually requires that size of storage.

**Algorithms** that use individual bit level programmability are far more likely to be random access across a smaller storage space than typical large block organized Flash memory devices.

**FRAM Technology** may very well be what you want to take a serious look at. FRAM reads and writes at the bytes and bits level (for bits you need to perform a read-modify-write operation). FRAM has no long multi millisecond write / erase times. Writes typically take place as fast as the serial interface can operate. FRAM also has impressively high write endurance numbers. [Cypress has a SPI interfaced FRAM device](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Cypress-Semiconductor/CY15B104Q-SXI/?qs=2De2tSDgB01Uyxkl7oDfXA%3D%3D) that is 4 Mbit (512K bytes) that should adapt well. You can also consider placing multiple devices to increase storage a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Flash memory, by definition, does not support bit-level erasing, only page or block level erasing. You might want to take a look at other types of nonvolatile memory that do support this type of operation, but it would be nice to know what your specific requirements are.

Comment: I have just edited my post, if you need more specific Information, please tell me.